# Using the Azure Pipelines to build our application we are recently facing an issue for Maven Test goal

Tags: selenium-webdriver

We are getting below issue
Java API connection is not establishing. pipeline responding with connections failure message

```
06:31:25 -\> 1 MetadataConfigE  - START TEST: Scenario_endpoint_200_V1
06:31:25 -\> 2 MetadataConfigE  - GET https://api-ststrt.dev.testinternal.site/%5C%5C\<application\>/notify HTTP/1.1
06:31:35 -\> 3 MetadataConfigE  - API call threw exception: 'api-ststrt.dev.testinternal.site: Temporary failure in name resolution', check logs for full stack trace.
06:31:35 -\> 4 MetadataConfigE  - comparing '0' to expected value of '400'
06:31:35 -\> 5 MetadataConfigE  -       FAIL TEST! '0' did not equal expected value of '400'
```

But it was working when we were using Jenkins.

Is it automation script issue or pipeline configuration issue?

Comment: Please don't post the same text multiple times. That definitely does not increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: If someone can help on above issue that will be great help .